Why can't a program identify which constructor to use because of cyclic-dependencies?
I have two classes: a 'transition' class and a 'state' class.I want to store in a state class a vector of transitions, thus I need to include "transition.h" in "state.h". On the other hand, in transition I want to store a pointer to the state class object, thus I need to include "state.h" in "transition.h".
In the methods of transition class I do not use any of the methods of the state class, so the only thing a transition needs to know about the class state is that it exists and has some public methods. But the problem is when I try to call a transition constructor inside of a state class method, it gives an error saying that there are no matching constructors for transition class object.
So, here are transition constructors:
 transition(std::shared_ptr<state>& from_state, std::shared_ptr<state>& to_state,
               std::unique_ptr<matcher>&& transition_matcher);

 transition(std::shared_ptr<state>& from_state, std::shared_ptr<state>& to_state,
               std::unique_ptr<matcher>&& transition_matcher, std::vector<size_t>& end_groups, std::vector<size_t>& start_groups);


Inside of a state class method I try to construct a transition object:
void state::add_transition(std::shared_ptr<state> &to, std::unique_ptr<matcher> &&transition_matcher) {
    transition t{std::make_shared<state>(*this), to, std::move(transition_matcher)};
    transitions.push_back(t);
}

The code block above gives an error saying No matching constructor for initialization of 'transition'
It suggests using these parameters for transition constructor:
int& from_state, int& to_state, std::unique_ptr<matcher>&& transition_matcher

I suppose it happens because of this cyclic dependecies, but I don't know why exactly.
I tried using forward declaration and putting class state; before transition class declaration. The result was that when I try to construct the transition object as I described above, it finds the corresponding constructor and lets me construct this object and lets me push it back to the vector. However i tried using an emplace_back() in this way:
void state::add_transition(std::shared_ptr<state> &to, std::unique_ptr<matcher> &&transition_matcher) {
  
    transitions.emplace_back(std::make_shared<state>(*this), to, std::move(transition_matcher));
}

I get an error for that saying
In template: no matching function for call to 'construct_at' error occurred here in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<transition>>::construct<transition, std::shared_ptr<state>, std::shared_ptr<state> &, std::unique_ptr<matcher>>' requested here in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::vector<transition>::emplace_back<std::shared_ptr<state>, std::shared_ptr<state> &, std::unique_ptr<matcher>>' requested here candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with _Tp = transition, _Args = <std::shared_ptr<state>, std::shared_ptr<state> &, std::unique_ptr<matcher>>]: no matching constructor for initialization of 'transition'

Can someone explain why was there a problem in the first situation and why is there a problem with emplace_back() in the second situation?

We need a [mcve]

Dupe: When can I use a forward declaration? and What are forward declarations in C++?

You said

On the other hand, in transition I want to store a pointer to the
state class object, thus I need to include "state.h" in
"transition.h".

This is incorrect, all you need is a forward declaration
class State;

Doing this instead of #include "state.h" will solve your problem.
You will be unable to use the State class in transition.h when it has only been declared using a forward declaration. So this might mean you need to move some code from transition.h to transition.cpp. In transition.cpp you can safely include both state.h and transition.h so there is no problem there.
